# How to serve static html pages inside colorbox?

Tags: jquery, grails, colorbox

I have few static html pages in my grails application to show up. But I am finding a hard time to achieve this. I need to display a .html file from the js script like this

```
function alertExpiry(){
    $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"50%", height:"50%", href: "expiry.html"});
}
```

I want that expiry.html page to show up. I placed that html file under views/home/expiry.html
Version: grails 3.2.9

Comment: What is the issue / error?

Comment: I think, this functionality has nothing to do with the grails, this is a simple jquary plugin and you have to open just a html page in iframe, this should work ideally.  You can check your browser console to debug the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **UrlMappings** file I put the following line

```
"/page/$id" (controller: "staticPage", action:"index", params:["id": "$id"])
```

And I wrote the following login in **StaticPageController**

```
class StaticPageController {
    GrailsConventionGroovyPageLocator groovyPageLocator

    def index() {
        if (groovyPageLocator.findViewByPath("/home/${params.id}") != null) {
            return render (view:"/home/${params.id}")
        }
        redirect(controller: "home")
    }
}
```

One more change I did. I changed that **expiry.html** page to **expiry.gsp** and now the link is

```
$.colorbox({iframe: true, width: "50%", height: "50%", href: "page/expiry"});
```

finally, it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve the static pages from a grails application, no need to add those pages inside the view directory, create a directory **home** inside the **web-apps** put all static html files inside this directory like,

> web-apps -> home -> expiry.html

now get this resource inside your colorbox jquery plugin as below

```
<div class="popup">
open colorbox
</div>

$(function() {
   $(".popup").colorbox({
    iframe:true,
    width:"500px",
    height:"500px",
    href : "YOUR_APP_NAME/home/expiry.html",
    onClosed:function(){ alert('popup icon closed !')},
   });
});
```

Grails project structure : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Grails/img/xfirstgrailsapplication10.png.pagespeed.ic.eLfC9gNB16.webp

Comment: Nitin **web-apps folder?** do you mean webapp under **src/main/webapp**. I did so. but no result. Anyways I found an another way for that. But how much legitimate not sure. Please check in my answer.

Comment: Nope, web-apps is the child directory of your project directory, usually where you keeps your all js, css, images etc. and this is the directory where all static resources are kept.

Comment: Nitin I didn't see any web-apps folder in my project. Am using intelliJ IDE and it places all the static resources in assets folder under grails-app. Hope you know grails file structure well. Do I need to create explicitly?

Comment: No its default, just minimize all the directories inside your project, then you will find that, and its a last directory of an application

Comment: No Nitin. I did minimize all. not found. I can send you a screenshot if you share your mail address. if you don't mind. Really appreciate your help

Comment: See this image http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Grails/img/xfirstgrailsapplication10.png.pagespeed.ic.eLfC9gNB16.webp

Comment: But in grails 3.2.9 the file structure is different Nitin. I checked in prior 3.2.9 it is there. I think here we have to create explicity? will check that one too

Comment: If not getting found, this directory might be removed in grails latest version, you could create your own instead of that, also could use asset directory if exists